# Easy JS image changer

Tags: javascript, image, loops

I have a simple onMouseOver and Out image changer.

```
<div id="img1" onMouseOver="changeBg('imgs/1col.png', 'img1')" onMouseOut="changeBg('imgs/1.png', 'img1')"></div>
        <div id="img2" onMouseOver="changeBg('imgs/2col.png', 'img2')" onMouseOut="changeBg('imgs/2.png', 'img2')"></div>

function changeBg (image, id) {
var div = document.getElementById(id);
div.style.backgroundImage = "url("+image+")";
```

}

However I have like 50 images I would like to apply this effect on, is there an easier way to write this, as a JS function to count automatically and get it to return values etc? so like:
"imgs/" + i + "col.png" "img" + i

Thanks for all you help

EDIT: anyone able to help on thiss?

Comment: Have you thought about using a javascript library such as jquery? It would certainly make writing code like this a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML:

```
<!-- Easier to add event handlers at once programmatically -->
<div id="img1">a</div>
<div id="img2">b</div>
```

The JavaScript (note that I'm using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)):

```
// Retrieve URL from ID
function imgUrlFromId(id, toggle) {
  var id = id.replace("img", "");
  return "url(imgs/" + id + (toggle ? "col" : "") + ".png)";
}

// Create function defining how to build the URL to the replacement images
function changeImage(e) {
  $(e.currentTarget).css("backgroundImage",
    imgUrlFromId(e.currentTarget.id, (e.type === "mouseover")));
}

// Bind mouseover and mouseout event handlers to each div with an ID
// starting with "img"
$("div#[id^=img]").each(function() {
  $(this).mouseover(changeImage).mouseout(changeImage)
    .css("backgroundImage", imgUrlFromId(this.id, false));
});
```

Comment: couldn't seem to get this working :/ but them again, i dont know jquery.
why are the "a" "b" in the div tags

Answer (score 0):

### TADA

**JavaScript:**

```
window.onload = function() {
    div = document.getElementById('images').getElementsByTagName('div');
    j = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
        if (div[i].className == 'img') {
            div[i].setAttribute('id', j);
            div[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + j + '.png)';
            div[i].onmouseover = function() {
                this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.getAttribute('id') + 'col.png)';
            }
            div[i].onmouseout = function() {
                this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.getAttribute('id') + '.png)';
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="images">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    ... for as many images you want
</div>
```

Comment: i cant use class="img" as i already have classes defined, jsut omitted them for brevity

Comment: Can't you add a second class? You can also do this without classes, then I have to modify the code a bit. By the way, why don't you use `img` elements? You can make it so that it adds 'col' to the `src` link when you roll over the images.

Comment: mmm il ltry it, never knew could add a 2nd class :D.

Comment: Separate them by a space like so: `class="class1 class2"`.

Comment: tried that, no luck :/, changed the top bit tooo becasue i use "bkimg"...
`<div id="bkimg">
         <div id="im1" class="web img" ></div>
            <div id="im2" class="log img" ></div>
            <div id="im3" class="web img" ></div>

window.onload = function() {
    div = document.getElementById('bkimg').getElementsByTagName('div');`

Comment: What you can do is, change in the script `if (div[i].className == 'img')` to `if (div[i].className == 'web')`, and use your old class. You can also remove the `id`s because they are automaticly added with the script. The `div` tags then becomes `<div class="web"></div>`.

Comment: i have 4 classes pre-set however, not just web.
thanks for all your help so far